# Does GCDWebSever support web sockets?

Tags: ios, swift, webserver

Need to implement a self-host Web-Server running on iPad, looks like [GCDWebServer](https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer) is a great option.
However the author does not intend to support for WebSocket, see link [here](https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer/issues/172).

Question: Is there an alternative to GCDWebServer that support WebSocket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

End up with Swifter which is not as mature, but good enough.
See the project [here](https://github.com/httpswift/swifter).